Sum of squares two different ways
A question popped into my head while watching 3B1B's video about the Gaussian integers and the formula for $\pi$ and thinking about Ramanujan's two ways of writing 1729 as the sum of perfect cubes two ways. Can we do the same thing with Pythagorean triples?
That is to say, does there exist a perfect square (say $c$) that can be written as a sum of squares of positive integers two different ways ($a^2+b^2=c \text{ and }x^2+y^2=c \text{ but } \{a,b\} \ne \{x,y\}$)?
I know there are solutions if c is not a perfect square (e.g. $65=8^2+1^2=4^2+7^2$) but is that necessary for c?

See the Jacobi Sum of two squares Theorem

$625=25^2=0^2+25^2=15^2+20^2=24^2+7^2$, for example.

Example of A349324 shows six representations of $15697403475^2=a^2+b^2$.

Use the composition law for sums of squares - just like for differences $\ \ $

We have that $625 = 15^2 + 20^2 = 7^2 + 24^2$. In general, you can generate infinitely many of them by combining Pythagorean triples.
